# PHP/MySQL live search with JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this HTML ad jquery code

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Search: <input type="text" name="search" id="search" /> <input type="submit" id="SearchGo" value="Search" /> <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('input#SearchGo').on('click', function(){
var searchid = $('input.search').val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "tickets.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid').val(decoded);
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchid').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
});
</script>
```

i want to have a live search function so when i click the submit button the page doesnt reload.

this code is on my tickets.php page (same as the post page)

on tickets.php i have the following:

```
if($_POST) {
    //run search query
} else {
    //run normal select query
}
```

but no results are showing

Comment: Jquery .live is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement most likely fails. You can check to see if the strings has characters (not empty)

```
if ($.trim(searchid).length > 0)
```

Comment: Please also add an error method to your ajax call and check your browser console for errors.

Comment: this isnt doing anything still

Answer (score 0):

change

`<input type="submit" id="SearchGo" value="Search" />`

to

`<input type="button" id="SearchGo" value="Search" />`

...and:

`var searchid = $('input.search').val();`

to:

`var searchid = $('input#search').val();`